# Dynamically Playing MP3 files downloaded with AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, mp3, google-translate, playback

I have the need to play an MP3 file on my website downloaded via AJAX like the "Listen" button on the Google Translate page (in fact, I'm doing the exact same thing). How is this done? I don't believe it's facilitated by Flash, so that's not the answer.

Comment: Google seems to be using flash.

Comment: @Uku Indeed, it appears to be using flash. That seems pretty weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest loading an iFrame with the sound file embedded within.  It's an ugly solution, but it's probably got the best crossbrowser support until HTML5 turns into a thing.